# Calculation of normal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

In the system illustrated in the image below, the floor has a coefficient of friction of $\mu$ and the masses are connected by a massless pole.  Assume the pole exerts a force $F_p$ on each mass. The problem this is taken from asks to find the initial accelerations of each mass.  Take $a_1$ as the acceleration for the mass on the floor and $a_2$as the acceleration for the mass on the wall.

I get the following equations of motion:

$Ma_1=F_p\cos{\theta} - \mu(Mg+F_p\sin{\theta})$

$Ma_2=F_p\sin{\theta}-Mg$

And the following relation assuming the velocity of each mass is 0 and $t=0$ with initial angle $\theta$:

$a_1=-a_2\tan{\theta}$

I can solve for $F_p$, $a_1$, and $a_2$ from the above equations without issue algebraically and get to a solution for the initial accelerations of each mass.   My answer doesn’t agree with the official solution, and the discrepancy is in the calculation of the friction force.

So my question is specific to the normal force exerted by floor which is used to calculate the friction force on the bottom mass in the expression for $a_1$, which I calculate to be $F_N=mg + F_p \sin{\theta}$. In the official solution for this problem the normal force is calculated as $F_N=mg$ which doesn’t make sense to me as if $F_p$ contributes to the net horizontal force on the bottom mass, it should also contribute to the net vertical force thus end up in the expression for the $F_N$ as in my solution.

So my question is my expression for $F_N$ that includes the vertical component of $F_p$ correct (and the official solution incorrect) or am I incorrect?  If I am incorrect where is my error in reasoning?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hint: "cut" the massless pole (cut method), which forces do you have for M on the ground?

Comment: Could you solve it?

Comment: I think you can calculate $F_P$.

Comment: Thanks for following up - I modified my question to include my setup for the problem and how I solve for F_p and the two accelerations.  Does this setup look correct? Not familiar with the cut method and tried looking into but couldn’t find good explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: Thanks Vincent - i have tried to edit my question to reflect a conceptual question - not that it matters but I am not a student and am self studying this material for fun so I don’t have instructors or relevant colleagues to bounce ideas/questions off of to check work or solidify my understanding - the challenges of self study…